# Vue.js Routing with back button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I already use this Vue.js Routing example application.

```
https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-2.0-simple-routing-example
```

In the `src/main.js`
I have so much data value .

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentRoute: window.location.pathname,
    token : "",
    errorMessage : '', etc...etc..
  },
```

Now with socket.io i set the token to `"sdawdda2d2ada2ad22ad"`

When application start than the currentRoute is equal with `"/"`
Its okey, the first page loaded. `src/routes.js`

```
'/': 'Home',
'/about': 'About'
```

When i want to check the /about (url: `localhost:8080/about`), than its works good , but the token and errorMessage  is empty again, because the app created again.

If i want to change page without lose the token value i can use:

```
this.currentRoute = "/about"       (url: localhost:8080)
```

Its works good , but the url not change, so i cant use back button in browser.
How can i separate my Vue app, if i dont want to lose token value when the browser go to /about?

Thanks so much!

Comment: don't use that example... use the official Vue Router library https://router.vuejs.org/en/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are moving from your `Home` route to `About` route, you need to use `<router-link>` to navigate.

From your `home` page, you can navigate to `about` page as follows:

```
<router-link to="/about">Go to my About Page</router-link>
```

That generates a regular html anchor tag `<a>` with the path set correctly. When you click on that, it will take you to the `about` component, and not refresh the entire html webpage (with app scripts) from server.

When only the route component gets changed, all your other Vue params like token on the Vue instance will remain.

Please take a look at the `vue-router` here: http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html

Remember to have a placeholder for routes in your main app as follows: `<router-view></router-view>`. Your `Home` and `About` component will get rendered into this `router-view` as you change routes.

Comment: Thanks, so much, i will try this. But its hard for me, because im not good in front-end tech. But i try it :)

Comment: Getting started link changed to: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

Answer (score 36):

you can do something like `this.$router.go(-1)` or `vm.$router.go(-1)` to go forward `this.$router.go(1)` for more [click here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n)

Comment: If i follow your method the props which were present in the previous page would be set to null. Is there a way to maintain the prop value while routing to the previous page.

Comment: @beingyogi: I'd simply store prop values in `localStorage` before navigating to another page and reload them in `mounted()` event. This works with browser's own Back button too.

Answer (score 5):

**simple way**

```html
<template lang="html">
  <div>   
    <button @click="goBack">
      Back
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      goBack() {
        this.$router.go(-1)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```